# Do we have to write first this series in terms of factorials to test it?

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series

The series
$$\sum_{n=1}^{n=\infty}\frac{1 \cdot 4...(3n+1)}{n^2}$$
**First , if we want to test the series ,can we apply the ratio test directly in this way?( or we must convert it in terms of factorials?)**
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{1 \cdot 4...(3n+1) \cdot (3n+4)}{(n+1)^2}\frac{n^2}{1 \cdot 4...(3n+1)}$$
$$\lim_{n\to\infty}\frac{(3n+4)n^2}{(n+1)^2}=\infty$$
Hence the series diverges.

**Second , can we find a general formula for the above series in terms of factorials ?**

for example , if we have a series of the form
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{1\cdot 3 \cdot 5 ... (2n+1)}{2 \cdot 4 \cdot 6...(2n)}$$
we can convert it in terms of factorials to apply ratio test on the new form
$$\sum_{n=1}\frac{(2n+1)!}{(n!)^22^{2n}}$$

Comment: No, you don't *have to* convert the general term of a series to something in order to use this or that converngence test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** Yes, you can directly apply Ratio Test as you did. Ratio Test is generally applied when you have expressions with factorial like $n!$, exponential like $a^n$, $n^{th}$ root like $\sqrt[n]{a}$ or a multiplication like $1 \cdot 4...(3n+1)$ as in your example. When I see one of those, I try to apply Ratio Test first myself but that doesn't mean that the result of the test will be conclusive for all the cases when one of those expressions appear. So it is just an observation actually.

**2)** Generalization a formula with factorials may not be appropriate every time (This question may be an example for this). But in the example you gave, yes you can convert it to an expression with factorials and apply Ratio Test.

Answer (score 2):

An easier way to proceed here is to note the $n$th term is at least $(3n+1)/n^2 > 1/n.$ Since $\sum _n 1/n$ diverges, so does the given series.